# Two lights & two switches, one light doesn't work?

Tags: lighting, ceiling, switch

[image]Please could you advise me, why isn't second ceiling light working? Two lights and two switches, power does not appear to be going to second light, both switches are working. Have I wired first light which has three cables coming out of the ceiling incorrectly?

Hi. Landing ceiling lights one at either end of the corridor, two separate switches (one at each end of corridor) that work both lights. One light doesn't appear to have any power, possible wired the light as shown in picture incorrectly

Comment: can you provide pictures of the wiring of the lights and the switches?

Comment: Are they three way switches? Is there a scenario where you can get that second light to work at all?

Comment: Where's the line, is there a load, a diagram with hot/neutral/switched/ground identified at each junction would help, are the switches two independent switches or three way switches. There's currently not enough detail to provide an answer to this.

Comment: Hi. Landing ceiling lights one at either end of the corridor, two switches that work both lights. One light doesn't appear to have any power.

Comment: In the 'it never hurts to ask the obvious' category, have you confirmed the light bulb in the other fixture is functional?